# Why is the message "Akka version is not supported by Typesafe Console: 2.3.4"?

Tags: scala, sbt, akka, typesafe-console

I'm getting this exception when I do a `sbt compile` 
My `build.sbt` contains the following entries.

```
scalaVersion := "2.10.3"
val akkaVersion = "2.3.4"

libraryDependencies ++= Seq(
  "com.typesafe.akka" %% "akka-actor" % akkaVersion,
  "com.typesafe.akka" %% "akka-testkit" % akkaVersion,
  "com.typesafe.akka" %% "akka-persistence-experimental" % akkaVersion)
```

Any idea what's causing this ?

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: Akka version is not supported by Typesafe Console: 2.3.4
    at scala.sys.package$.error(package.scala:27)
    at com.typesafe.sbt.atmos.AtmosRun$.supportedAkkaVersion(AtmosRun.scala:65)
    at com.typesafe.sbt.atmos.AtmosRun$$anonfun$selectAkkaVersion$1.apply(AtmosRun.scala:58)
    at com.typesafe.sbt.atmos.AtmosRun$$anonfun$selectAkkaVersion$1.apply(AtmosRun.scala:58)
    at scala.Option.map(Option.scala:145)
    at com.typesafe.sbt.atmos.AtmosRun$.selectAkkaVersion(AtmosRun.scala:58)
    at com.typesafe.sbt.SbtAtmos$$anonfun$atmosDefaultSettings$26.apply(SbtAtmos.scala:159)
    at com.typesafe.sbt.SbtAtmos$$anonfun$atmosDefaultSettings$26.apply(SbtAtmos.scala:159)
    at sbt.Scoped$RichInitialize$$anonfun$map$1$$anonfun$apply$3.apply(Structure.scala:130)
    at sbt.std.Transform$$anon$3$$anonfun$apply$2.apply(System.scala:45)
    at sbt.std.Transform$$anon$3$$anonfun$apply$2.apply(System.scala:45)
    at sbt.std.Transform$$anon$4.work(System.scala:64)
    at sbt.Execute$$anonfun$submit$1$$anonfun$apply$1.apply(Execute.scala:237)
    at sbt.Execute$$anonfun$submit$1$$anonfun$apply$1.apply(Execute.scala:237)
    at sbt.ErrorHandling$.wideConvert(ErrorHandling.scala:18)
    at sbt.Execute.work(Execute.scala:244)
    at sbt.Execute$$anonfun$submit$1.apply(Execute.scala:237)
    at sbt.Execute$$anonfun$submit$1.apply(Execute.scala:237)
    at sbt.ConcurrentRestrictions$$anon$4$$anonfun$1.apply(ConcurrentRestrictions.scala:160)
    at sbt.CompletionService$$anon$2.call(CompletionService.scala:30)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:262)
    at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:471)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:262)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:744)
[error] (atmos:traceAkkaVersion) Akka version is not supported by Typesafe Console: 2.3.4
[error] Total time: 0 s, completed Aug 4, 2014 8:04:08 AM
```

Comment: What's inside `project/` folder? Are there any `*.sbt* and/or `*.scala` files? Is the `build.sbt` complete?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Did you by chance use Activator to create the application? Typesafe Activator contains the Inspect tab, which basically is what is left of the console (and uses sbt-atmos which is the project where the AtmosRun class is located). I had similar problems when running Akka 2.3.4 with the Activator. Not sure if it is fixed already in the current version. You might need to deactivate the inspect feature of activator in that case.

Comment: Akka 2.3.4 is supported by Activator 1.2.3 :-)

Comment: Yes I used activator to create it.I removed activator related files and it's working fine now.

Answer (score 2):

The Typesafe Console (which you seem to be using) has been discontinued. As the exception states: `Akka version is not supported by Typesafe Console: 2.3.4`.

The Typesafe Console has been discontinued. Please use the latest `Activator` https://typesafe.com/platform/getstarted or one of the other Akka monitoring solutions:

- http://kamon.io – open source, host yourself
- http://www.appdynamics.com – cloud or host yourself
- http://newrelic.com – cloud

Comment: @Konard -  I don't have any "direct" dependency in my build.sbt for typesafe console. However, I'm using a bunch of other 3rd party libraries (which may in turn using typesafe console.). Any idea how to find the culprit ?

Comment: Someone is including `atmos` (the console).

Comment: As mentioned by @pushy activator was adding console. I deleted activator related files and it works fine now.

Answer (score 0):

I had this problem. It seems an earlier version of console or activator (or something) installed an "atmos shim" in my project. Deleting both of these files solved the problem:

```
activator-sbt-atmos-akka-shim.sbt
project/activator-sbt-atmos-akka-shim.sbt
```